# NullPointerException in TiffImageReader

Tags: java, image, io, nullpointerexception

I try to read a lot of tif-Images with the TiffImageReader of Java, but at some files a NullPointerException is thrown. The only difference to the other files is that they have been changed by a program and the value of photometric interpretation is "YCbCr". I do not exactly know which program was used to change the images, but the properties say: "Pixel Translations Inc.".

My Code:

```
IIORegistry registry = IIORegistry.getDefaultInstance();  
registry.registerServiceProvider(
  new com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageWriterSpi());  
registry.registerServiceProvider(
  new com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageReaderSpi());
return ImageIO.read(file);
```

Is there any solution to avoid the NullPointerException?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageReader.read(TIFFImageReader.java:984)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
at Anonymisieren.ImageTools.readImage(ImageTools.java:176)
```

I've already tried to change the Metadata, but this is not possible with the TiffImageReader before reading the image.